# Geographically dispersed servers, PostgreSQL, and JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

My database server's TIMEZONE is UTC. I have Java servers in various time-zones that interact with the database. Naively I discovered that if I have a TIMESTAMP field that there is really no way for me to set it from the Java server's JPA code as UTC. I guess I naively assumed that if JDBC would always send dates over with TZ info and the database server could appropriately convert in or out based on its time zone. But no. :(

Here's the rub. I may have Java servers in various timezones interacting with this database sever. If something happens at 9pm on the east coast and 6pm on the west coast I would like both of those events to be stored in the database at the same time. Duh, right?

So what's the solution, I suppose I could put all my Java servers in UTC. But there seems like there should be a less heavy handed solution. I guess I could also SET TIME ZONE on every transaction, but ugh.

I know I will get some answers saying I should only store longs in the database, and while I appreciate the veracity of this answer I do want to retain TIMEZONE and DATE fields in my database tables. So I am looking for other types of answers. Thanks.

Comment: don't forget to sync the clocks using NTP

Comment: I think you want `timestamp with time zone`, not `timestamp`. If you also wish to retain the time zone / offset, you must store it separately - the naming of the `timestamp with time zone` type is rather deceptive in that regard. Thank the SQL standard.

Comment: How will that make a difference if the postgres server is running in UTC?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use TIMESTAMPTZ fields for these instants in time. Something like "when was the user created" should never be stored with a TIMESTAMP field as by default it does not hold TZ information. The JDBC driver handles these quite arbitrarily. For example, consider the following:

Assume your JVM is in the America/Los_Angeles zone while your database server is in UTC.

Then create the following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE test (
   id   INTEGER,
   ts   TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   tswz TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 );
```

If you issue from PSQL:

```
 INSERT INTO test(id) values(1);
```

You will get identical values for "ts" and "tswz". Both will be the current UTC time. However if you perform the SAME EXACT query from Java using the JDBC driver then "ts" will be the current time in Los Angeles and "tswz" will be the UTC time.

I don't know HOW the driver conveys to the server the JVM timezone in this case because we are defaulting the field on the server. They say they do not set the time zone for the session, but they must. Either way, if you use a TIMESTAMPTZ field then you will get the same instants from any JVM regardless of what timezone it happens to be in.