# How can I create columns with type Date and type DateTime in nestjs with typeORM?

Tags: mysql, date, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I am new with nestjs. How can I set columns that accepts Date format and dateTime format?

Not in both cases, the columns are two differents column, one accept Date and other dateTime.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can see the docs [here](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/column-decorators) that explains the *@Column* decorator. In *@Column* there is an option called *type* -> here is where you specify which type of date you want to store for that specific column.

More on column types [here](https://typeorm.io/#/entities/column-types).

For example (using *PostgreSQL*):

```
@Column({ type: 'date' })
date_only: string;

@Column({ type: 'timestamptz' }) // Recommended
date_time_with_timezone: Date;

@Column({ type: 'timestamp' }) // Not recommended
date_time_without_timezone: Date;
```

Note that `date_only` is of type **string**. See [this issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2176) for more information.

Moreover, automatic dates for certain events are possible:

- *Creation Date*, available via [`@CreateDateColumn()`](https://typeorm.io/decorator-reference#createdatecolumn) decorator.
- *Last Updated Date*, available via [`@UpdateDateColumn()`](https://typeorm.io/decorator-reference#updatedatecolumn) decorator.
- *Deletion Date*, only when *soft delete* is enabled, available via [`@DeleteDateColumn()`](https://typeorm.io/decorator-reference#deletedatecolumn) decorator.

```
@CreateDateColumn()
created_at: Date; // Creation date

@UpdateDateColumn()
updated_at: Date; // Last updated date

@DeleteDateColumn()
deleted_at: Date; // Deletion date
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. The type returned by typeorm for `type: 'date'` is a string - not a date object with the time set to 0. See https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2176

Comment: @sarfata I've updated my answer. Let me know what you think!

Comment: @CarloCorradini awesome! I like that you clearly recommend `timestamptz` too ;)

Comment: would timestamp be ok when using mysql? as timestamptz is not supported?

Comment: Ok, but how to use "timestamptz" with GraphQL? What should I use inside ObjectType and InputType to fix the issue with the wrong DateTime types?

Comment: @EugeneZalivadnyi I use [GraphQL Scalars](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-scalars) library with a date/time scalar mapping. E.g. `GraphQLTimestamp` for UNIX epoch or `GraphQLDateTime` for UTC. You decide what best suits your needs since the input given to the scalar is always a `Date` instance (`timestamptz`).

Comment: @CarloCorradini any reason why "timestamptz" is recommended over "timestamp"?

Comment: @bilard See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22925669/6676781

Comment: Anyone who comes here and doesn't find how to include the columns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64941148/node-js-add-created-at-and-updated-at-in-entity-of-typeorm

Answer (score 46):

How about ?

```
@CreateDateColumn()
created_at: Date;
    
@UpdateDateColumn()
updated_at: Date;
```

EDIT

You can find more info [here](https://typeorm.io/#/entities/special-columns)

Comment: This should be the correct answer, simple and handled automatically by typeorm on save.

Comment: I don't believe this should be the correct answer, or upvoted as it is. There are more uses for timestamp columns than just created_at and updated_at values

Comment: @Eazash that's why I provided a link to the rest of the docs :D

Answer (score 15):

To add more to this ticket as DateTime was not even mentioned:

```js
  /**
   * Start DateTime
   */
  @Column({
    type: 'datetime',
    default: () => 'NOW()',
  })
  @Index()
  start: string;

  /**
   * End DateTime
   */
  @Column({
    type: 'datetime',
    nullable: true,
  })
  @Index()
  end: string;
```

This is for those not wanting or needing to use

`@CreateDateColumn()`

`@UpdateDateColumn()`

Comment: Does this mean that `start` and `end` are of type `string` and not `Date`?

Comment: No, they are `type: 'datetime'`

Comment: Yes, that is w.r.t MySQL. I wanted to know about how they would appear in JS.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it. The name parameter represents the column name in the database. If you use the built in decorators it will handle updating the columns in without additional code.

```
@CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at'})
createdAt: Date;

@UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at' })
updatedAt: Date;

@DeleteDateColumn({ name: 'deleted_at' })
deletedAt: Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement...
When creating and wanting the result to only display the date, use:

@CreateDateColumn({ type: "date" })
createdAt: Date | string;

If not specified, the time will also be included.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work in any way, seems to be a bug in the decorators or a misunderstanding how they should work (NestJS 10.3, TypeORM 0.3.17, Postgres 15). I used this workaround with hooks instead:

```
class SomeEntity {

    @Column({
        name: 'created_at',
        type: 'timestamptz',
    })
    createdAt?: Date;

    @Column({
        name: 'updated_at',
        type: 'timestamptz',
    })
    updatedAt?: Date;

    @BeforeInsert()
    protected setCreatedAt(): void {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
    }

    @BeforeUpdate()
    protected setUpdatedAt(): void {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }
}
```