# Node.js add created_at and updated_at in entity of typeorm

Tags: node.js, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have `task` entity like this:

```
import {BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Task extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id:number;

    @Column()
    title:string

   @Column()
    description:string

}
```

I want to add created_at and updated_at field to this entity and populate it automatically with `Node.js` like `Laravel` framework. My database is `postgres`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Let's import first

```
import { CreateDateColumn,UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";
```

Add this fields and decarators in Entity

```
@CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)" })
public created_at: Date;

@UpdateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)", onUpdate: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)" })
public updated_at: Date;
```

Comment: I noticed Welisson Moura's answer did not  includ  extra properties for the `CreateDateColumn` and `UpdateDateColumn` decorators. Is there any reason for the extra properties you specified?

Comment: @penava What does `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)` actually do

Comment: @bilard save as 6 digit under second. 6 means save as micro second.

Answer (score 25):

```
import {BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, CreateDateColumn} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Task extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id:number;

    @Column()
    title:string

   @Column()
    description:string
   
   @CreateDateColumn()
   created_at: Date;

   @UpdateDateColumn()
   updated_at: Date;


}
```

Comment: how about to add timestamps fields to all entities?

Comment: @ShaSha you can use entity inheritance technique

Answer (score 16):

```
import { CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

@CreateDateColumn()
createdAt: Date;

@UpdateDateColumn()
updatedAt: Date;
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried all the previous ways you informed, but the only way that worked was this.

```js
import moment from "moment";

@CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

@UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;

@BeforeInsert()
insertCreated() {
    this.created_at = new Date(
      moment().tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    );
    this.updated_at = new Date(
      moment().tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    );
  }

@BeforeUpdate()
insertUpdated() {
    this.updated_at = new Date(
      moment().tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    );
  }
```