Timezone offset not showing in Springboot JPA
I have a Spring boot application with below entity
@Entity
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID transactionID;

    private Long fromAccount;

    private Long toAccount;

    private Double amount;

    private Double balance;

    @Column(name = "timestamp", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    private OffsetDateTime timestamp;
}

When I save this transaction to PostgreSQL table it correctly saves the data with timezone offset.
  amount | balance | from_account |            timestamp             | to_account |            transactionid
--------+---------+--------------+----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------    
     200 |     200 |            2 | 2024-04-25 02:15:30.570947+05:30 |            | a36114a7-ac90-42b1-adec-c910d5685330

But when I try to retrieve the transaction using findAllByFromAccountOrderByTimestampAsc(accNo). The timestamp does not contain the offset anymore.
{
    "transactionID": "a36114a7-ac90-42b1-adec-c910d5685330",
    "fromAccount": 2,
    "toAccount": null,
    "amount": 200.0,
    "balance": 200.0,
    "timestamp": "2024-04-24T20:45:30.570947Z"
}

I want to store the timestamp with server's timezone.
What am I doing wrong here ?

In PostrgreSQL data type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE is not intended to store timezone (btw there's no builtin timestamp data types which storing timestamp offsets/timezones). It stores timestamp in UTC, and RDBS makes timestamp conversions from client's timezone to UTC when any operations going on data. If you really need to store timezone then you need to store it in separate talbe filed as text. Meybe that will be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922155/postgresql-jdbc-and-timestamp-vs-timestamptz
